# aws redshift: getting max(id) taking lot of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have table created as

```
CREATE TABLE dbtest.testtable (

    id bigint NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)

    accountid bigint  distkey,

)
DISTSTYLE KEY
SORTKEY ( accountid);
```

It has a rows of 870,080,643

I am trying

```
select max(id) from dbtest.testtable
```

its takes 15 seconds

How to speed up this

I see the explan graph as

[image]

Comment: Did you try to sort in desc and take the first value

Comment: And the execution plan belongs to a count query. And you should use count(*) instead of count(id)

Comment: Why have you selected a SORTKEY of `accountid` and a DISTSTYLE of `KEY`? Is it due to the content of your data, or perhaps how the data will be most accessed?